# Why does odeint fail with the newer versions of odeint?

Tags: c++, boost, odeint, boost-multiprecision

I was struggling with the new version of boost. I am using odeint with mupltiprecision. The following piece of code can be successfully compiled with boost version 1.67.0. However, since version 1.68.0 and newer, I can no longer compile. In version 1.68.0 complex multiprecision numbers were introduced and I would like to use this datatype as well in my code. Can someone tell me where the error is in my code?

```c
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

typedef boost::multiprecision::mpf_float_100 mpf;
typedef boost::array< mpf , 1 > state_type;

void rhs( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const mpf t )
{
    dxdt[0] = ( - x[0] * sin( t ) + 2.0 * tan( t ) ) * x[0];
}

void write_out( const state_type &x , const mpf t )
{
    cout.precision(50);
    cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    bulirsch_stoer< state_type , mpf , state_type , mpf > stepper( 1E-20 , 0 , 0 , 0 );

    state_type x;

    mpf t = mpf("0.2");
    mpf dt = mpf("0.01");
    mpf t_end = mpf("1.5");

    x[0] = 1.15;

    integrate_adaptive( stepper , rhs , x , t , t_end , dt , write_out );
}
```

I am working on opensuse, compile with icpc or g++ 7.4.1. The error message that I get with icpc is quite long.

```
icpc -lgmp -I/userdir/boost_1_71_0/ code.cpp
/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/detail/extract_value_type.hpp(47): error: class "boost::numeric::odeint::detail::extract_value_type<mpf, void>" has no member "type"
      typedef typename extract_value_type< typename S::value_type >::type type;
                                                                     ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of class "boost::numeric::odeint::detail::extract_value_type<S, boost::enable_if<has_value_type<S, boost::mpl::bool_<false>>, void>::type> [with S=mpf]" at line 47
            instantiation of class "boost::numeric::odeint::detail::extract_value_type<S, boost::enable_if<has_value_type<S, boost::mpl::bool_<false>>, void>::type> [with S=boost::array<mpf, 1UL>]" at line 28 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/norm_result_type.hpp"
            instantiation of class "boost::numeric::odeint::norm_result_type<S, Enabler> [with S=boost::array<mpf, 1UL>, Enabler=void]" at line 89 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/controlled_runge_kutta.hpp"
            instantiation of "boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<Value, Algebra, Operations>::value_type boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<Value, Algebra, Operations>::error(boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<Value, Algebra, Operations>::algebra_type &, const State &, const Deriv &, Err &, Time) const [with Value=mpf, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, State=state_type, Deriv=state_type,
                      Err=state_type, Time=mpf]" at line 235 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer.hpp"
            instantiation of "boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result={boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result} boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::try_step(System, const StateIn &, const DerivIn &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &, StateOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations,
                      Resizer>::time_type &) [with State=state_type, Value=mpf, Deriv=state_type, Time=mpf, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), StateIn=state_type, DerivIn=state_type, StateOut=state_type]" at line 156 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer.hpp"
            instantiation of "boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result={boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result} boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::try_step(System, StateInOut &, const DerivIn &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &) [with
                      State=state_type, Value=mpf, Deriv=state_type, Time=mpf, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), StateInOut=state_type, DerivIn=state_type]" at line 393 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer.hpp"
            instantiation of "boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result={boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result} boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::try_step_v1(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &) [with State=state_type,
                      Value=mpf, Deriv=state_type, Time=mpf, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), StateInOut=state_type]" at line 135 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer.hpp"
            instantiation of "boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result={boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_step_result} boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::try_step(System, StateInOut &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &, boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<State, Value, Deriv, Time, Algebra, Operations, Resizer>::time_type &) [with State=state_type,
                      Value=mpf, Deriv=state_type, Time=mpf, Algebra=boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, Operations=boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, Resizer=boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), StateInOut=state_type]" at line 103 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/detail/integrate_adaptive.hpp"
            instantiation of "size_t={unsigned long} boost::numeric::odeint::detail::integrate_adaptive(Stepper, System, State &, Time &, Time, Time &, Observer, boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_stepper_tag) [with Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<state_type, mpf, state_type, mpf, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), State=state_type,
                      Time=mpf, Observer=void (*)(const state_type &, mpf)]" at line 45 of "/userdir/boost_1_71_0/boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_adaptive.hpp"
            instantiation of "size_t={unsigned long} boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_adaptive(Stepper, System, State &, Time, Time, Time, Observer) [with Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<state_type, mpf, state_type, mpf, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, System=void (*)(const state_type &, state_type &, mpf), State=state_type, Time=mpf, Observer=void (*)(const state_type &, mpf)]" at line
                      36 of "code.cpp"

compilation aborted for code.cpp (code 2)
```

Comment: Adding (to your question) the compilation error that you get (verbatim) as well as info on what compiler (and version) you are using and on what platform, would help.

Comment: See this bug report: https://github.com/boostorg/odeint/issues/40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `boost::multiprecision::number`, what makes `mpf_float_100` (and every other Boost.Multiprecision type) work, has an associated `value_type` since Boost 1.68 and because of that Boost.Numeric.Odeint treats it as a container when it is not. The way that Odeint checks whether a type is a container is by using a trait: `has_value_type`, specializing that trait for `number` should work:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

template< typename Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option Option >
struct has_value_type<boost::multiprecision::number<Backend,Option> >:boost::mpl::false_{}; //ADDED

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

namespace mp=boost::multiprecision;

typedef boost::multiprecision::mpf_float_100 mpf;
typedef boost::array< mpf , 1 > state_type;

void rhs( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const mpf t )
{
    dxdt[0] = ( - x[0] * sin( t ) + 2.0 * tan( t ) ) * x[0];
}

void write_out( const state_type &x , const mpf t )
{
    cout.precision(50);
    cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    bulirsch_stoer< state_type , mpf , state_type , mpf > stepper( 1E-20 , 0 , 0 , 0 );

    state_type x;

    mpf t = mpf("0.2");
    mpf dt = mpf("0.01");
    mpf t_end = mpf("1.5");

    x[0] = 1.15;

    integrate_adaptive( stepper , rhs , x , t , t_end , dt , write_out );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you also have a clue what concerns multiprecision and OpenMP? I posted this issue right here: [How to combine boost odeint with OpenMP and boost multiprecision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354098/how-to-combine-boost-odeint-with-openmp-and-boost-multiprecision)